# Can't get global_parameter to work with Terraform azurerm_data_factory

Tags: terraform, azure-data-factory

According to the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/data_factory#argument-reference) .. `global_parameter` is indeed a valid argument. However when trying to use it, my validate command reports that *An argument named "global_parameter" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a block of type "global_parameter"?*

My config is simply

```
resource "azurerm_data_factory" "adf" {
  name                = "adf-${var.project}"
  location            = var.az_location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  tags = {
    environment = var.environment
    project = var.project
  }

  global_parameter = {}
}
```

I am using version 2.81 of the azurerm provider.

Comment: Obviously ... when the provider recognizes it as a valid argument .. then I will use it with actual values.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation doesn't seem correct. It's not supposed to be an *argument*; it's actually supposed to be declared as a *block*. Hence this is incorrect:

```
global_paramter = {}
```

and this is correct:

```
global_parameter {}
```

(No equals assignment here)

The documentation says it's an argument while the error suggests you probably wanted a block instead of an argument.